# Monthly Climatology for Pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, mean, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with two years of monthly data `Y`. I need the second column `Y_avg` with the climatology to be able to subtract both.

```
              Y   Y_avg
T          X    
2000-01-31 1  51  63
           2  52  64
2000-02-29 1  53  65
           2  54  66
2000-03-31 1  55  67
           2  56  68
2000-04-30 1  57  69
           2  58  70
2000-05-31 1  59  71
           2  60  72
2000-06-30 1  61  73
           2  62  74
2000-07-31 1  63  75
           2  64  76
2000-08-31 1  65  77
           2  66  78
2000-09-30 1  67  79
           2  68  80
2000-10-31 1  69  81
           2  70  82
2000-11-30 1  71  83
           2  72  84
2000-12-31 1  73  85
           2  74  86
2001-01-31 1  75  63
           2  76  64
2001-02-28 1  77  65
           2  78  66
2001-03-31 1  79  67
           2  80  68
2001-04-30 1  81  69
           2  82  70
2001-05-31 1  83  71
           2  84  72
2001-06-30 1  85  73
           2  86  74
2001-07-31 1  87  75
           2  88  76
2001-08-31 1  89  77
           2  90  78
2001-09-30 1  91  79
           2  92  80
2001-10-31 1  93  81
           2  94  82
2001-11-30 1  95  83
           2  96  84
2001-12-31 1  97  85
           2  98  86
```

This is my temporal solution:

```
f = np.tile(np.arange(1,25),2)
df['Y_avg'] = np.tile(df.groupby(f).mean().values.ravel(),2)
```

But how can I do that more efficiently? 
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the Y_avg to be the mean by X and the month of T, right? Assuming the T level of your MultiIndex is a DatetimeIndex, use

```
gb = df['Y'].groupby([df.index.get_level_values(0).month,
                      pd.Grouper(level=1)])
df['Y_avg'] = gb.transform('mean')
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Answer works fine unless I misunderstand the question.

Comment: @jaime-ac Could you mark as answered or give me an upvote?

Answer (score 0):

Firts of all, I had a hard time recreating the dataframe copy-pasting the data, so
for all of you that may want to answer the question, you can recreate the example with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a date range, convert to list and duplicate
T = pd.date_range("2000-01-31", "2001-12-31", freq="M").tolist() * 2
# Create a list of repeated [1, 2] to match length of T
X = [1, 2] * (len(T) // 2)
Y = range(51, 99)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([sorted(T), X], names=("T", "X"))
df = pd.DataFrame({"Y": Y}, index=index)
```

Then to calculate the mean of Y with respect of level T, you can use the following code:

```
Y_avg = df.Y.mean(level="T")
df = df.join(Y_avg, on="T", rsuffix="_avg")
```

First, you can calculate the mean with respect to certain index using the level parameter of the [mean series method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mean.html). The you can perform a standard [dataframe join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to merge the Y_avg series with the dataframe on the "T" index. Please note that you must provide a suffix (rsuffix in this case) to properly deal with columns' names.